# Intermittent problem using TestContext.AddResultFile (MSTest || TFS)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

I'm using TestContext.AddResultFile to add logs to the attachments tab. The same code is used in every test case, but sometimes the test logs don't appear in the attachments tab. This inconsistency occurs in some test cases; in the same test case, the logs may appear in some runs but not in others.
Im using MSTest project.
Theres my code bellow:

```
            StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            logBuilder.AppendLine("");
            logBuilder.AppendLine("Test: Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode + " " + response.StatusCode);
            logBuilder.AppendLine("");
            logBuilder.AppendLine("Test: Response Content: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            logBuilder.AppendLine("");

            string logFilePath = Path.Combine(TestContext.TestRunDirectory, "TestName.txt");

            File.WriteAllText(logFilePath, logBuilder.ToString());
            TestContext.AddResultFile(logFilePath);
```

Is there anything in the code that could be causing this issue? Can I make any configurations in my pipeline to address this intermittent problem?
(TestName is the name of a TestCase that im running).

Comment: Hi, are the test cases that do not display the test log file in the attachment tab failed or successful? could you please share build/release logs with `system.debug=true` and pipeline sample code  to help us better understand your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, i use `VSTest@2`  task to try to reproduce the issue. Please check the following steps to see if you are missing some steps.

1.Please use `File.Exists(path)` function to check if the file you want to attach exists.

example

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
   string logFilePath = Path.Combine(TestContext.TestRunDirectory, "TestName.txt");
    if (File.Exists(logFilePath))
    {
        TestContext.AddResultFile(path);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("file not found");
    }
```

2 [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops). You will see Associated Automation method in Test case in Azure Devops after associating automated tests with test cases.
[image]
[image]
3 Add `VSTest@2` task in YAML pipeline.

```
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testPlan'
    testPlan: 'your test plan ID'
    testSuite: 'your test suit ID'
    testConfiguration: 'your test configuration'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    testRunTitle: 'add test result file'
```

If testMethod passed, the test log file will be published to Attachment Tab.
[image]
[image]

If the file cannot be found, the test logs don't appear in the attachments tab.
[image]
[image]

To make a summary, please check if the test log file exists and check your build/release log file to see if the file published successfully or you can share the pipeline logs with us to figure out why the attachments don't show.

Beside you can use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to get Get Test Result Attachments to check if any attachments are returned. If there are attachments from the response, please refresh the devops page and see if the files appear in the attachments tab.

Here is a similar ticket:

[TestContext.AddResultFile not working sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792638/testcontext-addresultfile-not-working-sometimes)